# Probability vs Odds

Tags: probability

I know what Probability & Odds ratio is, but I want to know under what circumstances each is used. When is Odds preferred over Probability?

Comment: Odds are usually harder to grasp for the reader. https://senseaboutscienceusa.org/know-the-difference-between-odds-and-probability/

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3519388/990182) answer from [Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you were aware of **Probability & Odds**,

- Use **odds** to describe that if there are any chances of the occurrence of an event or not.
- Use **probability** to determine the likelihood of the happening of an event, i.e. how often the event will take place.

**Interpretation**

**Odds** usually ranges from ***zero to infinity***, wherein zero defines the impossibility of occurrence of an event, and infinity denotes the possibility of occurrence. Conversely, **probability** lies between ***zero to one***. So, the closer the probability to zero, the more are the chances of its non-occurrence and the closer it is to one, the higher are the chances of its occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

Odds describe association between two events. You can't have an odds without a reference event. Probability, on the other hand, simply describe the likelihood of a particular event.